# custom attributes using threejs

Tags: three.js

I was reading on ThreeJS custom attributes and got confused about how to set them up.

So i've seen that we add an attribute to the geometry attribute list and then the same to the ShaderMaterial attributes list ?

My question is how to add custom attributes in 3js ?

Comment: Can you share some source code or a JSFiddle to let us know what you've tried already?  It's a little hard to tell what you need without more context.

Comment: Search the three.js examples: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_custom_attributes.html

Comment: I think i go it.
So first i add an attribute to the geometry attribute list, call it Attrib1

Then on the the shader attributes, i've added that specific attribute to the list

geometry.attributes =
{
   Attrib1: { ... }
}

then in the material

attributes: { Attrib1: { type: "f", value: null } }

it seems to work.

I came here because examples online were a bit confusing

Answer (score 3):

The new version (r67) features `RawShaderMaterial` which allows full control of attributes/shaders. Here's an example:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_rawshader.html

If you want something less "raw" but still performant, here's an example using `BufferGeometry` and `ShaderMaterial`:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles.html

And, if you want to use `Geometry` here's an example of that too:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_custom_attributes.html

Comment: Cool, RawShaderMaterial sounds much better to me. Thanks

Comment: That last example uses buffergeometry.. From what I see there isn't a way to pass custom attributes to the shaders using a normal geometry.